# Ember.js: getting model relationships from component's javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-components

I am building a component, and I have noticed a behaviour that seems very odd to me. My component is invoked as follows:

```
{{my-component model=model}}
```

My model contains a relationship as follows:

```
type: DS.belongsTo('type')
```

Now, in `my-component.js`, if I log to console `this.get('model.type.name')` (or `this.get('model').get('type').get('name')`), I get `undefined`. However, if in `my-component.hbs` I insert `{{model.type.name}}`, the value is displayed correctly.

I don't really understand this behaviour: how can I access a model's relationship from within a component's javascript just like I do in the component's Handlebars template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ember-data, relationship is treated as Promise so you should use `then` for the result.

```
this.get('model').get('type').then((result) =>{
 console.log(' Name ', result.get('name'));
});
```

Refer:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however, if I try to do `this.get('model').then(model => { console.log(model) })`, I get `TypeError: this.get(...).then is not a function`. I don't understand why this is the case :/

Comment: Your snippet of code actually works, though, so I'm wondering why `this.get('model').then` is not a function...

Comment: Relationship such as `belongsTo` and `hasMany` will return `Promise`. here `model` is not releationship its resolved model from `model` hook. You can do `then` only for promise

Comment: Yes, makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!